# Is it bad form to build a new DefaultStyledDocument every time I wish to clear one and start anew?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

My program ends up taking a `StyledDocument`object from one `JTextPane`(A) and passing it off to another `JTextPane`(B). When I have finished passing, I wish for the `JTextPane`(A) to be clear of text and any formatting and basically be a fresh build of the object with its default `JTextPane` settings. To do this, I am currently doing something like:

```
//make things
JTextPane inputField = new JTextPane();
JTextPane outputField = new JTextPane();

//move inputField text (with formatting) from inputField to outputField
StyledDocument doc = inputField.getStyledDocument();
EditorKit kit = inputField.getEditorKit();
outputField.setStyledDocument(doc);
outputField.setEditorKit(kit);
outputField.revalidate();

//reset the inputField so that it's fresh and ready for new input
inputField.setStyledDocument(new DefaultStyledDocument());
inputField.setEditorKit(new StyledEditorKit());
```

I realize in this example I don't have any text or formatting being moved(just a blank document object), but those are the operations I am performing, and am curious if "newing" a kit and document are a lazy way to reset my `JTextPane` to default settings. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is better to reuse existing objects instead of creating new ones.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov: why do you say this? I see nothing wrong with Lucas's plan. This code does not appear to be at any time or memory critical portion of his project, and the old Document will likely be GC'd when memory is needed.

Comment: I know it's better to reuse before renewing, but this case isn't such that I can simply reuse. If I did, both my JTextPane A and B would reference the same document object. Changes to one JTextPane's document would be reflected in the other JTextPane's document, as they are the same document. I was curious to know if this way of ensuring this concurrency is avoided is bad form. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I did not say that Lucas' plan is wrong. It will work. But in complex applications it is better to reuse existing objects. GC can clear unused object references, but it is a good practice to do not create unecessary objects, when we can reuse existing ones.

Comment: Would you have tips for how I'd reuse my old document object without having both JTextPanes reference it? I do not like to 'new' objects when I can avoid it, certainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it's absolutely fine to create a new instance of document. In fact it's faster because listeners don't update views to reflect empty `Document` and then the new `Document's` content.

BTW: no need to reset kit if it's the same class. It's enough to call `setDocument()`

Comment: I will keep on as I've been doing, with the adjustment to not resetting the kit. Good info about the listeners, thank you.